# Removing a row from the android database

Tags: android, database

I'm currently working on adding, viewing and removing values in an android database but unfortunately the book I have only covers the adding and viewing part so I've come here for help.

I have a class called DeleteEntry which you enter a variable moduleDelete which get passed through to the class DeleteEntryViewModule. This class then uses this value to return all values on that row using this showEvent() method

```
private void showEvents(Cursor cursor) {
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder("Saved Events:\n");
while (cursor.moveToNext()){
    long id = cursor.getLong(0);
    String module = cursor.getString(1);
    String day = cursor.getString(2);
    String starttime = cursor.getString(3);
    String duration = cursor.getString(4);
    String typeofsession = cursor.getString(5);
    String room = cursor.getString(6);
    builder.append(id).append(": ");
    builder.append(module).append(": ");
    builder.append(day).append(": ");
    builder.append(starttime).append(": ");
    builder.append(duration).append(": ");
    builder.append(typeofsession).append(": ");
    builder.append(room).append("\n ");
}
TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
text.setText(builder);
}
```

How do I take the values from the builder and place them into variables so I can execute this code.

```
private void removeEvent (String module, String day, String starttime, String duration, String typeofsession, String room){
    try{
    SQLiteDatabase db = events.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues ();
    values.put(DAY, day);
    values.put(MODULE, module);
    values.put(STARTTIME, starttime);
    values.put(DURATION, duration);
    values.put(TYPEOFSESSION, typeofsession);
    values.put(ROOM, room);
    db.replaceOrThrow(TABLE_NAME, null, values);
    }catch(SQLiteException ex){
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "Broken", 10);
        toast.show();
    }
```

}

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using below code instead of db.replaceOrThrow

```
return db.delete(TABLE_NAME, MODULE + "="
            + module, null) > 0;
```

Can you explain why you are using db.replaceOrThrow ??

Comment: I was following what I had done to add a row db.insertOrThrow but didn't relise the replace will just fill columns with null. I've inserted your amendment and got everything compiling correctly but when I actually run it is throwing up an sql exception. I've debugged it to narrow it down to this android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: CM111: , while compiling: DELETE FROM timetable WHERE module = CM111 but I can't see anything wrong with that sql statement?

Thank you for your help